# Is it possible to use C++/winrt to build COM object instead of for example using ATL?

Tags: c++-winrt

Has anybody tried to use C++/winrt to create Win32 COM objects? The C++/winrt docs document that consuming them is possible and of course creating "new" UWP COM objects. I was wondering if for some simple scenario's one could use the C++/winrt headers instead of ATL to generate some simple COM objects.

Comment: The [implements struct template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/implements) seems like a good candidate. While you can limit the implicit interfaces through [marker structs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/implements#marker-types), I'm not aware of a way to remove the `IInspectable` implementation. Even if not required, implementing additional interfaces will not violate COM rules.

Comment: If you are interested in creating a classic COM objects without using ATL you can have a look at the [RuntimeClass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/runtimeclass-class) and [How to create a Classic COM Component Using WRL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/how-to-create-a-classic-com-component-using-wrl)

Comment: @IInspectable The implements class template will only implement IInspectable if you actually implement an IInspectable-derived interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a COM component with C++/WinRT. Here’s an example of a COM executable server but the principles and techniques are much the same for a DLL.

https://gist.github.com/kennykerr/d983767262118ae0366ef1ec282e428a

For a DLL you just want to make sure you export an implementation of DllGetClassObject and DllCanUnloadNow. Otherwise, its just like any other DLL and you can use the winrt::implements class template to implement the various classes and factories.

Comment: Hi Kenny, 
Thanks for the link, your sample is exactly what I was looking for. It seems that some things need to be done differently than with ATL, but the basics are covered. Will post a link here to github repo, when my experimental code is good enough,

Comment: Hi Victor, does your experimental code work?, I am also thinking of using C++/WinRT for COM component.

Comment: @Kenny Kerr, I have an unmanaged C++ desktop legacy library in DLL(Binary, I don't have source code), that I would like to expose it to managed application (C# Form App), I see following options: PInvoke or COM interop or C++/WinRT, I would like to know what is the best option, any insights would be appreciated. PS: We have done ATL components previously , currently working on UWP with C++/WinRT components on other projects.

Comment: Is C++/CLI a good interop option today for interop technology in exposing my C++ code to managed app?